# Как остановить GZipStream используя комбинацию клавиш

Tags: c#

Есть метод, реализующий сжатие файлов, с созданием архива по указанному пути:

```
public int Action(string typeJob,string fileInput, string fileOut)
{            
    if (FileExistCheck(fileInput, fileOut))
    {                
        using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(fileInput, FileMode.Open))
        {               
            using (FileStream targetStream = File.Create(fileOut))
            {
                switch (typeJob)
                {
                    case "compress":
                        using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(targetStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                        {
                            sourceStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);
                            return 0;
                        }
                    case "decompress":
                        using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(sourceStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                decompressionStream.CopyTo(targetStream);
                                return 0;
                            }
                            catch (InvalidDataException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Возможно путь к архиву указывает на файл иного типа");
                                File.Delete(fileOut);
                                return 1;
                            }
                        }
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Первый аргумент указан неверно");
                        Console.WriteLine("Следует выбрать compress или decompress");
                        File.Delete(fileOut);
                        return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else return 1;
}
```

Как можно реализовать остановку этого процесса с вызовом какого либо метода, нажатием клавиши/сочетания клавиш? Много видел информации как остановить вечный цикл, но про `FileStream` не нашёл.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте `CancellationToken` и метод `CopyAsync()`:

1. Измените сигнатуру вашего метода:

   ```
   public async Task<int> ActionAsync(
       string typeJob,
       string fileInput,
       string fileOut,
       CancellationToken token)
   ```

   А в теле используйте `CopyToAsync()`, передавая ему `token`. Вместо:

   ```
   sourceStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);
   ```

   Пишите:

   ```
   await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(compressionStream, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
   ```

   Аналогично и с `decompressionStream`.
2. Где-то уровнем выше создавайте `CancellationTokenSource` и передавайте его токен в ваш метод `Action()`:

   ```
   var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
   ActionAsync(..., ..., ..., cts.Token);
   ```
3. В нужный вам момент (нажатие клавиши), отменяйте задачу:

   ```
   cts.Cancel();
   ```

P.S. Механизм обработки исключений в C# был придуман как замена кодам ошибок. Поэтому я бы посоветовал избавиться от возвращаемого значения метода (`int`).

Comment: Кроме tpl способа нет?

Comment: @АнтонЛихацкий а вам все равно нужен второй поток чтобы читать с клавиатуры, независимо от выбранного вами способа прерывания процесса. Так что почему бы и не tpl?

Comment: На деле получилась китайская грамота. внутри метода if(token.IsCansellationRequested) а где этот Requested настраивать непонятно. Снаружи?  Что почитать посоветуете, вообще непонятно как это применить если честно

Comment: в каком месте в теле метода используется вот эта конструкция: await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(compressionStream, token).ConfigureAwait(false); ??

Comment: @АнтонЛихацкий обновил ответ. Про отмену см. п. 3. Почитать можно [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/12.5.php) и [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/168669/), например.

Comment: @АнтонЛихацкий где вы в этом ответе нашли проверку `if(token.IsCansellationRequested)`?